# Newbie regarding android back button on mobile website

Tags: android, mobile, web, mobile-website

I understand that android has this few functions such as onBackPressed() which utilizes the back button on the android phones for native android applications,

I was wondering if it was possible to utilize this backbutton on a mobile website, are there any function or codes for them. Could anyone point me to any reference on these on how to go about coding it if possible.

The other question that I would like to ask as well is that is this also possible for IOS. Considering that the IOS back button is usually built into the application itself.

Added for clarity,
I'm designing my application using mainly jquery stuff.

Comment: Still looking if anyone else might have other insights on this! as of 25/9/2013

Answer (score 1):

If you are planning to use twitter bootstrap for you mobile website, may be this what you are looking for   [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16870007/how-to-close-a-bootstrap-modal-with-the-browser-back-button-instead-of-going-bac)

If you plan to use phone gap, you may want to have a look at 
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12557249/how-do-i-disable-the-phones-back-button-in-android-using-jquerymobile-phonegap)

If you are using only jquery, then there is no way to disable the hardware back button as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11425820/disable-hardware-back-function-jquery-mobile)

Comment: I'm using jquery instead of twitterbootstrap

Comment: my second link might answer your need

Comment: oh thanks... so it has to be wrapped with phone gap or something? phone gap does kills off a little of the idea of designing a mobile web